# PDF content remains constant while generating pdf using ABCpdf.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, abcpdf, abcpdf9

I am trying to generate dynamic pdf using ABCpdf.net in C# .net MVC web application.

```
        Doc theDoc = new Doc();
        theDoc.Rect.Inset(72, 144);
        string url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.OriginalString.Replace("GeneratePDFUsingStream", "");

        theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
        int theID;
        theID = theDoc.AddImageUrl(url,true,1200,true);

        while (true)
        {
            theDoc.FrameRect();
            if (!theDoc.Chainable(theID))
                break;
            theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
            theID = theDoc.AddImageToChain(theID);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= theDoc.PageCount; i++)
        {
            theDoc.PageNumber = i;
            theDoc.Flatten();
        }

        using (Stream theStream = theDoc.GetStream())
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=MyPDF.PDF");
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", theStream.Length.ToString());
            long theLen = theStream.Length;
            byte[] theData = new byte[theLen >= 32768 ? 32768 : (int)theLen];
            while (theLen > 0)
            {
                theStream.Read(theData, 0, theData.Length);
                Response.BinaryWrite(theData);
                theLen -= theData.Length;
                if (theLen < theData.Length && theLen > 0)
                    theData = new byte[(int)theLen];
            }
        }
        theDoc.Clear();
        Response.End();
```

Everything is working fine but the contents of my html is constant in the pdf file.

As per their site recommendation([ABCpdf](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/3-concepts/g-htmlrender.htm)), i tried following:

> Disable cache via code(last parameter-disablecache is set to true: theID = theDoc.AddImageUrl(url,true,1200,true);
>
> Pass a new url each time to AddImageUrl method.

None of these suggestions seems to work. I am not sure if this is due to my browser settings.

Please suggest.

Comment: What part of your code is creating dynamic content in pdf?

Comment: By dynamic pdf i meant, it will change everytime user selects generate pdf button.

Comment: But what should be changed in the pdf? You code doesn't have anything which writes different content to pdf. It's the same code writing the same content to pdf. How do you expect it to be different?

Comment: The code is generating pdf using html . AddImageUrl method take site url and coverts html to image and embed it to pdf.

Comment: Does that url change? The html content is different everytime? Are you sure converting html to image works properly?

Comment: yeah i have cross checked this. I even tried with changing the url each time as per ABCpdf suggestion.